# Ember Simple Auth Device persist authentication information in LocalStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ember.js, devise

I can't seem to find a direct answer that deals with a code example of how it works but I'm using `simple-auth 0.7.3`. with `ember-cli` and `simple-auth-devise`. 
I can authenticate just fine but once I refresh the page session is killed. I saw a previous post and the guy didn't have the right object but what about a case when the object is correct?

```
{"authenticator":"simple-auth-authenticator:devise","user_id":53,"user_token":"Vm2TwefZCwaAo8hfg&pT","user_email":"user9@redphone.com"}
```

Im not the sharpest knife in the draw but I'm hoping someone can shed some light on why a session is killed and how/where to prevent it.

Comment: Do you see the token in you localStorage after you login? And what previous post do you mean?

Comment: Do you have something like this: `ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  store: 'simple-auth-session-store:local-storage'
}` in your envirnoment.js?

Comment: Sorry I for the late response I almost lost hope on an answer but yes:
`ember_simple_auth:session ``{"authenticator":"simple-auth-authenticator:devise","user_id":53,"user_token":"Vm2TCzk7CwaAo8zYCzpT","user_email":"user7@email.com"}`

Comment: @albertjan i am referring to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020545/ember-js-ember-simple-auth-persist-authentication-information-in-localstorage-do

Comment: also my ENV 
`ENV['simple-auth-devise'] = {
    authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise'
  };`

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/packages/ember-simple-auth-devise/lib/simple-auth-devise/authenticators/devise.js#L91) method get called when you refresh?

Comment: in my initializer
simple-auth-config.js
`export default{name:'simple-auth-config',before:'simple-auth',initialize:function(){var tokenEndpoint='/'+ENV.NAMESPACE+'/users/sign_in';ENV['simple-auth']={session:'session:withCurrentUser',authorizer:'simple-auth-authorizer:devise',authenticationRoute:'/sessions/new',routeAfterAuthentication:'manager'};ENV['simple-auth-devise']={identificationAttributeName:'email',serverTokenEndpoint:ENV.APP.HOST+tokenEndpoint,};window.ENV=ENV}};`

Comment: should it be called after the init function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the what is being put in the localstorage:

```
{"authenticator":"simple-auth-authenticator:devise","user_id":53,"user_token":"Vm2TwefZCwaAo8hfg&pT","user_email":"user9@redphone.com"}
```

Ember simple auth is using "user" as a resourceName in the config:
[Ember Simple Auth Devise](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-cli-simple-auth-devise)

The resourceName is normally added when the server endpoint is expecting more than email,password. In this case the endpoint expects user_email,user_password.

And by default When you refresh a page simple auth checks the localstorage for
email,token. You have to also change that to user_email, user_token.

in the Config:

```
ENV['simple-auth-devise'] = {
authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise',
serverTokenEndpoint:         ENV.APP.HOST+'/' + ENV.NAMESPACE +'/users/sign_in',
resourceName:                'user',
tokenAttributeName:          'user_token',
identificationAttributeName: 'user_email'};
```

And that resolves the persistence issue.